# Are empty HTTP requests malicious?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, http, attacks

I have seen multiple empty http request log entries from Apache:

```
HOST:443 REMOTEIP - - [DATA AND TIME] "-" SIZE SIZE "-" "-"
```

Are these malicious attacks, or some misconfiguration on my side?

Comment: That first `SIZE` is actually the return code, isn't it one of 400 or 404?

Comment: The IP is not corresponding to the loopback or the IP of the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Empty responses are perfectly normal if e.g. the HTTP return code is 304 (Not modified). The client sending the request is sending headers like If-Modified-Since or If-None-Matches and the server uses them to determine that nothing changed and sends an empty response, allowing the client to use its cached copy.